# How to convert big hex String to int?

Tags: java, hex

Ok I have this hex string **"efe4b4f355de4cbc"** which I want to convert to integer. In python I do this:

```
print int("efe4b4f355de4cbc",16)
```

and the output I get is **17286140226965490876**.

Now when I try to do the same in Java using the following code:

```
long convertedHex = Long.parseLong("efe4b4f355de4cbc", 16);
```

All I get is

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "efe4b4f355de4cbc"

But why?

Anyhow then I though I should try a BigInteger so next thing I did was this

```
long convertedHex = new BigInteger("efe4b4f355de4cbc", 16).longValue();
```

Now the result I get is **-1160603846744060740** but that's not what I want. I want the same result as in python language.

Comment: Does `17286140226965490876` fit in a `long`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'm not sure about the Long max capacity. That's why I tried BigInteger next

Comment: You tried `BigInteger`, then you used its `longValue` method. What does its `longValue` method do?

Comment: String s = "efe4b4f355de4cbc"; BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(s, 16);      System.out.println(bi); on my pc gives 17286140226965490876 so you better switch to mine... ;)

Comment: Also, _I'm not sure about the Long max capacity_:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: @PetterFriberg That's strange! Actually I'm trying this on an android phone!

Comment: Dont convert to Long its to small!, Long.MAX_VALUE = 9223372036854775807

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I can't find the duplicate post, can you provide a link?

Comment: You cannot cast to long, it won't fit.

Your value = 17286140226965490876
Long.maxValue = 9223372036854775807

All you can do is 

BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(s, 16); 
System.out.println(bi);

Comment: Ok seems you guys are right. Converting to .long messes things up. So I think I will do my calculations in BigInteger format until the number becomes small enough to fit in an int or long field. Thank you all!